# .net Compact Edition 2.0, SQL Server Compact Edition and replication

Tags: .net, sql-server, compact-framework

I have been tasked with creating a mobile application for a Windows 6.0 CE device which is running .NET 2.0.7045.0 Compact Framework.

I have SQL Server 2005 Express running on my local machine and I want to let the Mobile Application have a replication or snapshot of my database, so the users can update the data in the field. Once they return they can sync back up with the device and update the Database with the updated data.

I have zero experience with this, so any help would be appreciated.

I have managed to get my IDE (Visual Studio 2008 Pro) talking to it and I can run my Applications and debug on it.

I assume once the device has been attached to it, it can connect to the computer ipaddress\instance or something?

Does this sound like the correct way to do it?

Cheers, Sarkie

Comment: Sarkie not putitng this as an answer, but you could also look at the Microsoft Sync framework, it allows you to synchronize between two data sources.  Data sources can be databases, Folders, outlook calendars.  The framework does require a fair amount of custom code but may be worthwhile taking a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sounds right. Your PDA will have an IP address assigned to its ActiveSync connection, and so will your PC (have a look under Network Connections, there should be a Windows Mobile Adapter there and you can look up the PCs IP address there).
That is assuming it uses ActiveSync, but you do mention Windows CE, so maybe you connect it in a different way?

I assume you already know how to get the database replication going? If not, here's an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151323.aspx) to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Seems I can't publish using SQL Express! :( After an hour or messing about with it!

Comment: What are you trying to publish from SQL Express? You are using SQL Server Compact on your CE device, right? Have a look here for more info about merge replication between SQL Compact and SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172367.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using RDA (Remote Data Access) - which is well supported by SQL Server Express - instead of Merge-Replication to achieve what you need.  While Merge-Replication is more flexible, it requires making changes to the host database.  RDA is easier to use and only requires a basic setup and DLL to be added to SQL Server.

See [Microsoft's information on that.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172917.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework) its cool and fast way.